# Replace formulas in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to write a code to replace formulas in my excel sheet. So that I can make it a macro and then run it on-demand on specific sheets. Its trying to find if a particular cell in Sheet "Credit" is empty or not, if empty show 0 else show negative of the cell value.

The macro says "running" for 8 seconds and then exits with no errors or messages and my cell contents stay intact.

What could be reasons why this won't be working? and please ignore my variable naming and style of concatenating the strings (newbie here) and suggest if it can be done differently

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim row, col, find, replace, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
row = Array(2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50, 54, 58, 62, 66, 70, 74, 78, 82, 86, 90, 94)
col = Array("F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU")
'
    
For Each c In col
    For Each r In row
            
            s = ",0,"
            t = """"
            u = "=IF"
            v = "="
            w = "-"
            x = "(Credit!$"
            y = "$"
            z = ")"
            
            
            find = v & w & x & c & y & r & z
            ' =-(Credit!$F$2)
            replace = u & x & c & y & r & v & t & s & w & x & c & y & r & z & z
            ' =IF(Credit!$F$2="""",0,-(Credit!$F$2))
            Cells.replace What:=find, Replacement:= _
                replace, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
                xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, _
                FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

(UPDATE)
Thanks to @topsail's answer, was able to modify his answer little and able to get the results with this edit -

```
For Each cell in Worksheets("2023").Range("A1:BI80").Cells
   ...
   ...
         If cell.Formula = formula_old Then 
            cell.Formula = formula_new 
         End If
   ...
   ...
Next cell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course your macro would do nothing if nothing was found. I'm not big fan of find/replace in code, when it isn't necessary. You can check your cells without "finding" them, by using their addresses.

Also, I would prefer to check for an empty cell with `=If(LEN(A1)=0)`, because this works on real empty cells (cells with nothing in them) as well as cells that contain empty strings (`""`).

So here's a variation of your code that should be easier to think about and test.

Note that your test is *very strict*. The cell contents must be exactly what you are looking for. If the formula, for instance, was `=-(Credit!F6)` or `=-Credit!F6` instead of `=-(Credit!$F$6)` - then again, nothing would happen.

```
Sub Foo()

Dim c As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim addr As String
Dim formula_old As String
Dim formula_new As String
    
    For c = 6 To 47 '//F to AU
        For r = 2 To 94 Step 4 '// 2,6,10,... 94
            addr = Cells(r, c).address
            formula_old = "=-(Credit!" & addr & ")"
            formula_new = "=IF(LEN(Credit!" & addr & ")=0,0,-(Credit!" & addr & "))"
            '//Debug.Print addr & " " & " | " & Cells(c, r).Formula & " | " & formula_old
            If Cells(r, c).Formula = formula_old Then
                Cells(r, c).Formula = formula_new
            End If
        Next r
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks very promising and thanks for a much neat code, but when I tried found out the logic was little wrong. I am not trying to change current cell's formula with same address from "Credit" sheet. I need to lookup each cell and if the address is in the formula, then replace as such.